# Asking how to achieve the design problem in flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart, flutter-layout

Hello Guys I would like to ask is it possible to achieve this kind of design using code? I really got stuck, here is design I would like to achieve
[image: Design needed to achieve]

but the real problem is I only achieve this

[image: Design I tried using code to achieve]

this is my sample code:

in my main:

```
return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xff012a60),
      body: Stack(children: <Widget>[
        /*_AnimatedCircle(
          outerController: outerController,
          innerController: innerController,
        ),*/
        _OuterCircle(circleColor: Colors.blueGrey[900].withOpacity(.8)),
        Column(children: <Widget>[
          const Spacer(flex: 50),
          Expanded(flex: 30, child: Container(color: Colors.white)),
          const Spacer(flex: 20),
        ]),
        Row(children: <Widget>[
          const Spacer(flex: 80),
          Transform.scale(
            scale: 2.5,
            child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.2,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.red, shape: BoxShape.circle)),
          ),
        ]),
        // _OuterCircle(circleColor: Colors.blueAccent.withOpacity(.25)),
        Row(children: <Widget>[
          const Spacer(flex: 80),
          Column(children: [
            Spacer(flex: 60),
            Transform.scale(
              scale: 2.5,
              child: Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.2,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.05,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.green)),
            ),
            Spacer(flex: 24),
          ]),
        ]),
      ]),
    );
```

and this is my other class

```
class _OuterCircle extends StatelessWidget {
  const _OuterCircle({Key key, this.circleColor}) : super(key: key);

  final Color circleColor;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Transform.scale(
        scale: 2,
        child: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.47,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: circleColor),
        ));
  }
}
```

Please help I really stuck how to achieve this kind of design in dart code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is easier to break down the geometry problem from the largest area to small area.

The key point of achieve this is using `Clip` ([ClipOval](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipOval-class.html), ClipRect...)

1. The upper part can be draw by using *right circle to clip left circle*
2. The lower part can be draw by using *right circle to clip inner rectangle*

[image]

1. Scale the stack area
2. Draw large left circle (area 1)
3. Draw middle white rectangle (area 2)
4. Draw right circle with rectangle inside (area 3)
5. Draw the middle intersection part (area 4)

Widgets in used: `ClipOval`, `FractionallySizedBox`, `AspectRatio`,

**The left Big Circle**

```
class BigCircle extends StatelessWidget {
  const BigCircle({this.color,Key key}):super(key: key);

  final Color color;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: 1,
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: color,
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**The custom oval clipper (clip right white circle area)**
[image]

```
class CustomClipOval extends CustomClipper<Rect> {
  @override
  Rect getClip(Size size) {
    final width = size.width * 0.42;
    return Rect.fromLTRB(
      size.width - width,
      (size.height - width) * 0.5,
      size.width,
      (size.height + width) * 0.5,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Rect> oldClipper) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

**Finally the stack**

```
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: const Color(0xff004471),
  body: Transform.scale(
    scale: 1.19,
    child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
      // Area 1
      const Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: BigCircle(
          color: Color(0xff022c66),
        ),
      ),

      // Area 2
      Align(
        alignment: const Alignment(0, 0.4),
        child: FractionallySizedBox(
          heightFactor: 0.23,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),

      // Area 3
      ClipOval(
        clipper: CustomClipOval(),
        child: Container(
          alignment: const Alignment(0, 0.46),
          color: Colors.white,
          child: FractionallySizedBox(
            heightFactor: 0.14,
            child: Container(
              color: const Color(0xff335f86),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),

      // Area 4
      ClipOval(
        clipper: CustomClipOval(),
        child: const Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: BigCircle(color: Color(0xff647294),),
        ),
      ),
    ]),
  ),
);
```

Comment: hello thanks for reply, i would like to ask how about the part which rectangle have curve one? which i have circle in picture? I needed the curve edge one, how do I achieve that?

Comment: I wrap the whole rectangle inside the `ClipOval` of area 3. Rectangle out of the circle will be cut.

Comment: Thx a lot for your help, really help my day, plus a little tweaking then it's done